# App rating for UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

If I submit an iPhone/iPad app that downloads HTML based post bodies, that could contain links to anywhere on the internet. (however the site it is downloaded from is strictly moderated), and when pressed those links open a UIWebView so that the linked website can be viewed in the app itself. Will an age rating be applied to the app?

Comment: It seems likely/possible based on what I have seen... kind of a grey area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You have to filter all UIWebView links to only site(s) under your control unless you want an Adult/17+ rating.  Apps have been reported to be rejected for not doing this.

Comment: "Apps have been reported" = mine was.

Comment: So to be 100% crystal clear... my situation is that I will have a `UIWebView` that will link to `http://www.mycompanywebsite.com/my_special_url_only_used_by_my_app`. This webpage will be links to our other products (and our partners products). The links will be to the app store, and other websites. How can we be sure that Apple will deem these to be appropriate? Thanks!

Comment: (and does it make a difference whether the links from that page open in safari as opposed to opening inline within the web view?)